# Routing doesn't work after Dockerizing Angular app

Tags: angular, docker, dockerfile, angular-routing, angular7

Am new to Angular and Docker. I have developed an Angular 7 application and trying to dockerize it. I did see many tutorials and was able to build the Docker image.
Below is my Dockerfile

```
FROM nginx:1.13.3-alpine
## Remove default nginx website
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*
COPY ./ /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

And i run the docker container using command

```
docker run -d --name containerName -p 8082:80 imagename
```

My container did start and after looking in the browser http://IP-address:8082/ I could see index html of my app. Apart from that none other url of my application like the login page (http://IP-address:8082/login) or dashboard (http://IP-address:8082/dashboard) works. I see 404 page not found issue. What else is missing to make sure routing works in my dockerized container?

Below is my default.conf file

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    #charset koi8-r;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    root           html;
    #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
    #    include        fastcgi_params;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #    deny  all;
    #}
}
```

And my docker version is Docker version 17.03.2-ce. 
Any help appreciated

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is happening because the base `nginx` image will try to serve the requests from the `docroot`, so it will try to find a `login.html` when you send a request to `/login`.

To avoid this, you need nginx to serve the `index.html` **no matter the request**, and thus letting `angular` take care of the routes.

To do so, you will need to change your `nginx.conf`, which is currently in the image, to include the following :

`try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;`

Instead of the default being:

`try_files $uri $uri/ =404;`

You can do so in many ways, but I guess the best approach is to have an extra command in your `Dockerfile`, that copies over the nginx configuration like so :

`COPY nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`

And have that `nginx/default.conf` file in your directory (containing the default nginx configuration) with the command specified above replaced.

**EDIT**

There is already images that does exactly that, so you can just use an image other than the official one, that is made specifically for that, and it should work fine: [example](https://hub.docker.com/r/trion/nginx-angular/)

Comment: i added this in Dockerfile "FROM trion/nginx-angular:latest" , though the container is running, i don't see my index.html also now. It says page is not working. http 502

Comment: I just checked his source code, he adjusts nginx to listen on 8080, thus it's changed, you can either map it to 80 on local host using `-p 80:8080`, or just do it customized as mentioned before the edit

Comment: @ abdullahkady i have edited the question with default.conf file. i dont see try_files part you mentioned at all. Where exactly should i change in my default.conf file?

Comment: Just add it under your `location` as the third line there